# view method in a smart contract changed to weird strings unintentionally

Tags: blockchain, solidity, polygon, smartcontracts

Hi I deployed a smart contract on Mumbai testnet and one of view methods in the contract suddenly stopped working as its name (or at least displayed) got weird like this.

```
cuº?TÔÿÅ‡ÃØ" #ra]„àU½{kYeCÀv`±m^‹c!ÀßedÌ+±'H¿%›©FIRST BLOCKCHAIN NOVEL
```

It was working fine yesterday when I deployed but today it stopped working so I checked the contract and found the above.

Deployed contract is [here](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0xAa32f6f2997f2A36FaaB03dec8d6a24765EebC1c#readContract)

Does anyone know what happened?

Could I fix it without deploying again?

In the front end app, I get this error.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="getAllNovels()", data="0x", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.6.4)
```

[update]
I deployed again and same thing happened...
contract is [here](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x80Be7237f512Db1f72EE0041bAAb4478D4936568#readContract)

[console error]
[image: console error]

Comment: This error is related to front and not smart contract, check front-end code and the network.

Comment: @AmirHabibzadeh Thank you for your answer! I see. I didn't know the front end causes this kind of issue!! What kind of code in the front end can cause this? I am using ethers.js and Vite with React/Typescript.

Comment: Did you check contract addresses and network you are testing the app?

Comment: @AmirHabibzadeh
Yeah. It seems fine to me.
Actually when calling view function to fetch some data from smart contract, it sometimes fails but sometimes succeeds and idk why.
Got an error like the image above. (see [console error])
Also my repo is [here](https://github.com/masafumimori/blockchainnovel)